# Accessing User ID from window.LocalStorage

Tags: django, vue.js, django-rest-framework, django-authentication

I have a DjangoRestFramework / Vue.js application.
For now I was getting my logged user with `this.requestUser = window.localStorage.getItem("username");`
I just needed my `requestUser` to check if a user was logged or not.
Now I have to "POST" data via an endpoint, but in my backend, DRF is expecting an `ID` not a `string` value.
So I checked my window.localStorage with the 'developer tool' and only my username value is stored, not its value.

I have few options:

> -create a new endpoint that will fetch an user ID from its value. And then on `created()` run a function that will save it into
> `window.localStorage`
>
> -modify my models and serializers so I can use my user value instead of its ID to interact with my endpoints.
>
> -or simply there is a configuration that I am not aware of than can save my `user.id` as well as my `user.username`

In DRF I am using plain `django.contrib.auth` for my User model. What is the best approach for my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using authentication, then you can get the `id` from `request.user.id` in the backend.

> `request.user` typically returns an instance of
> `django.contrib.auth.models.User`

[Reference](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/requests/#user)

Comment: But I need the `id` frontend.

Comment: If you need an `id` in the frontend simply to send it to the backend, then you don't need an `id` at the frontend, because if you are logged in, then the `request` object has access to the loggedin `User` object to fetch the `id`.